FastAPI endpoint does not generate swagger doc for body parameter created without using Model
I have an API endpoint in FastAPI wherein I'm not using Models to access request body. I'm instead using the built-in type Body with a description.
@vault_router('/secret')
def get_secret(
    token: Annotated[str, Header(description="Requires token to be sent in headers as access_token")],
    request: Request,
    path: Annotated[str, Body(description="key-vault path which needs to be accessed")], 
    keys: Annotated[List | None, Body(description="list of keys to fetch from the specified path")]=None
):
     # code goes here

Redoc generates a documentation that perfectly describes the parameters as Optional and Required with the correct decsription:

However, SwaggerUI does not:

I'm unable to find any solution on Internet. Even if I use Models I cannot describe the arguments as I desire with comments, required, optional, etc.
My inclination is towards not using Models for this solution.

I don't quite understand your question. What you see at the picture you shared is example value. If you switch to Schema you will see body schema with comments, required, optional, etc.

like I mentioned, my inclination is towards not using Schema for this solution. My question is - I am using Annotated and Body in the correct manner and yet the docs are not generating the description. Why?

Please, pay attention: at the picture of Readoc's documentation, the block's name is "Request body schema". On the picture of Swagger's documentation, the name of the block is "Example value". If you switch to the "Schema" tab, you will see exactly what you want - the description of your fields with required, description, etc.

Thankyou for the response. I am pretty new to Swagger UI. Wasn't aware of this.

In FastAPI, Swagger UI and ReDoc handle documentation differently. ReDoc supports the display of Optional and Required fields correctly when using the built-in FastAPI types like Body, Query, or Header, while Swagger UI might struggle to render such information as expected.
FastAPI’s behavior might be due to how Swagger UI interacts with FastAPI’s type annotations and the use of Annotated.
nstead of relying only on the combination of Annotated and Body, you can create a Pydantic model for the request body and manually specify the required and optional nature of fields. Then, use this model with detailed descriptions in a way that works for both Swagger UI and ReDoc.
from fastapi import FastAPI, Header, Body, Request
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from fastapi.routing import APIRouter

app = FastAPI()

vault_router = APIRouter()

class SecretRequestBody(BaseModel):
    path: str = Field(..., description="Key-vault path which needs to be accessed")
    keys: Optional[List[str]] = Field(None, description="List of keys to fetch from the specified path")

@vault_router.get("/secret")
def get_secret(
    token: str = Header(..., description="Requires token to be sent in headers as access_token"),
    request: Request,
    body: SecretRequestBody = Body(...),
):
    # code logic
    return {"message": "Accessing secret"}
    
app.include_router(vault_router)

This approach will work better in Swagger UI because it leverages FastAPI’s model-based documentation generation, which is more compatible with Swagger’s spec.

thankyou for the response. I am well aware of this solution. My question is more inclined towards how to implement this without using Models. My APIs have a diverse usage of request body. Every API would require a different model this way and my project is not big enough to write Models for every API, without it being reused any place else.

I don't see any difference between these two approaches. Looks like both of them generate the same schema. Could you point me out to the difference?
